# What are the default numbers of spring boot server.jetty.acceptors and spring boot server.tomcat.max-connections

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jetty

I hesitate to use springboot-jetty instead of springboot-tomcat, now, I want to compare performance of jetty and tomcat. What are the numbers of server.jetty.acceptors and server.tomcat.max-connections

Answer (score 2):

You can get all default values from `spring-boot` [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). 
Extract for asked values: 
`server.jetty.acceptors=-1`

`server.tomcat.max-connections=10000`

Answer (score -1):

the number of server.jetty.acceptor and selector is based on cpu cores. https://www.jianshu.com/p/77068cd014f9